# Is crying during salah disruptive?

Tags: salat, muslim-practices

It is laylut al qadr tonight, and before i prayed maghreb, my parents had gotten into an argument and things have occurred. i was about to miss my maghreb prayer so i just tried to get it out of my head and prayed. Alhamdulilah i was focused but i suddenly broke down into tears. i was surprised as i couldn’t even catch my breath while praying, yet i was still reading properly and focused on my prayer.
My question is, is this a disruption to my prayer or a good sign? i am quite worried about if it disrupted my praying or not.

Comment: Salam and welcome to ISlamSE the Q&A site about Islam to learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 1):

First of all scholars make a distinction between separate cases:

1. crying due to some worldly matter or because of something related to the prayer like khushu' (concentration) on the verse read or out of fear from Allah.
2. whether it was with a loud sound or soundless
3. whether it was voluntary or involuntary.

One could further add in relation to the 2nd point the length of the crying with sound.

Of course crying due to something related to the worship is good and basically not invalidating your prayer. Since Allah says:

> And they fall upon their faces weeping, and the Qur'an increases them in humble submission. ([17:109](https://legacy.quran.com/17/109))

And it was reported:

> Narrated Mutarrif bin Abdullah bin Shikhkhir (RA) from his father, who said, "I saw Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) when he was engaged in prayer, and heard a sound from his chest, like the bubbling of a pot, from weeping." (See in [Bulugh al-Maraam](https://sunnah.com/bulugh/2/88))

While in case of a worldly matter it isn't the same and must be discussed in detail.

However I'd like to address the topic whether crying can invalidate the prayer rather than whether it is disruptive as the later is rather a subjective matter. And of course the longer one cries and the louder it would be more and more disruptive. But as a Muslim the most important question  in this regard remains whether it will to invalidating ones worship?

A soundless crying also isn't an issue, but scholars further detailed on crying with sounds and whether this sound sounds like 2 letters or a word or so... See for example on islamweb Fatwa#[85706](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/85706/crying-while-praying-and-quran-is-recited)

> But, the scholars rule out any sound that might constitute a word of two letters, as such a sound nullifies the prayer according to them.
> Allah knows best.

#### Scholarly positions on crying while praying

I've translated and summarized to some extent the following scholarly views mainly from [islamonline](https://fiqh.islamonline.net/%D8%B6%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9/) -in Arabic- citing [al-Mowso'a al-Fiqhiyyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Encyclopedia_of_Islamic_Jurisprudence&oldid=1059406033) الموسوعة الفقهية الكويتية please take them with the necessary care!

- The Hanafi school of fiqh regards this as something which takes you out of the prayer they regard it as if you were talking instead of reciting the prayer. And therefore it would invalidate your prayer.
  The detail when it is with sound is if it is on more than two letters, or on two original letters, but if it is on two letters of the addition, or one of them is from the letters of the addition and the other is original, it does not invalidate the prayer in both cases.
- The position of the Maliki school of fiqh can be summarized by saying if it was with a sound and for a worldly matter without being overpowered (due to this worldly matter, be it an injury, calamity etc.)  it is similar to talking and would be judged based on whether it was voluntary or not, as for the voluntary it is invalidating the prayer by default, while the involuntary would only invalidate the prayer if it was for long time and one should perform sujud sahw for a short crying.
- As for the Shafi’is, crying in prayer (with sound) -in the most correct view- if two letters appear in it, then it invalidates the prayer, because it is like talking, even if the crying is from the fear of the Hereafter. And in the second view: it does not invalidate because it is not called a speech in the language, and nothing is understood from it, so it was more like an abstract sound.
- As for the Hanbalis, they believe that if two letters of crying, or groaning out of fear, or groaning during prayer are not invalidating it, because it can be regarded as remembrance of Allah. And it was said: If it was involuntary, otherwise it will be invalidated. Similar to the case if it was not out of fear of Allah, because its like spelling, and indicates by itself the meaning, like speech. Ahmad said about whining: If it is often, I hate it, i.e. from pain, and if it necessitates crying in it, it is hated like laughing, otherwise it is not.

So if you cried without a sound and as it seems involuntarily it shouldn't invalidate your prayer as per the above quoted views.

Answer (score 0):

Crying during salah (prayer) is not necessarily disruptive as it is a personal expression of emotion and a natural response to the spiritual experience of prayer. However, it is important to maintain composure and not become so overwhelmed with emotion that it interferes with the ability to properly perform the prayer.

According to Fiqh.[Islamonline](https://fiqh.islamonline.net/en/does-crying-in-prayer-nullify-it/),

> Crying for fear of Allah is a virtuous deed. It brings about Allah’s
> mercy, forgiveness and pleasure. At-Tirmidhi narrated on the authority
> of Ibn Abbas that Allah’s Messenger (peace and blessings be upon him)
> said: “Two eyes are never touched by the Hell-fire: the eyes (of a man
> who) shed tears for fear of Allah and the eyes (of a man who) kept
> awake to guard (Muslims) for the sake of Allah.” The majority of
> Muslim jurists say that crying or weeping out of piety and fear of
> Allah for remembering the Hereafter — whether in a loud or a low
> voice— does not nullify prayer. In the same way, crying and moaning
> out of pain do not nullify prayer. However, scholars of the Shafi`i
> School of Fiqh opine that crying in general nullifies prayer, no
> matter what the reason for crying is.

Read More on islamonline :
https://fiqh.islamonline.net/en/does-crying-in-prayer-nullify-it/

If one feels that their crying is disrupting their ability to concentrate or perform the salah, they may want to take a moment to collect themselves before continuing. It is also important to remember that crying during salah is not a measure of one's piety or devotion, and it is perfectly acceptable to experience different emotions during prayer.

A hadith:

> Abu Mutarrif reported: I saw the Messenger of Allah, peace and
> blessings be upon him, while he was praying. His chest made a sound
> like a boiling water pot from his crying.
>
> [Sunan Abī Dāwūd 904](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:904)

Grade: Sahih (authentic) according to Al-Albani